# MultiValueMap Lambda Issue

Tags: java, java-8

I recently moved from php to java, so my java skills are pretty low.

In my code i got a MultiValueMap named queryParams

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams;
```

A sample value can be  `{matchedMe=[11,22]}`

Required, i need to get list [11,22] to be set on variable listOfIds, so i wrote the code below.

```
List<String> listOfIds = null;  
queryParams.forEach((k, v)->{               
        if(k.equals("matchedMe")){
            listOfIds =  v;
        }               
    }
);
```

Problem:
getting errors as : lambda local variable viewedIds defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively fin

**Questions**

1. How to solve this issue?
2. What will be the minimum code if i need list and not list from MultiValueMap queryParams;

Comment: what is *i need list and not list from MultiValueMap queryParams* suppose to mean actually?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the `getOrDefault` or `get` method

```
List<String> listOfIds = queryParams.getOrDefault("matchedMe", emptyList());
```

As the `MultiValueMap<K, V>` extends `Map<K, List<V>>`, You can directly use the methods defined for the `Map` interface

Comment: this assume that `getOrDefault` exists and the OP hasn't said what `MultiValueMap` is or coming from

Comment: there are more things after the edit 1) what package is `MultiValueMap` from 2) should the resulting List be null or empty (is case of value not being present) 3) should you return a `new` List or one that still is in the map (suppose you alter your copy of the list... ). P.S. This is either way, *the* best option. 1+

Answer (score 0):

With lambda, as with any anonymous classes, you cannot assign a new value to a property outside of lambda. `listOfIds` is (in fact) final, but in Java 8 this keyword is not mandatory by the compiler, although the rule stays the same.

You can simply call for the value:

```
List<String> listOfIds = queryParams
.getOrDefault("matchedMe",Collections.emptyList()); // will return values, or empty List (to prevent null values)
```

or

```
List<String> listOfIds = queryParams.entrySet().stream()
.filter((k,v)-> "matchedMe".equals(k)) // filter by key
.findFirst()
.map(Map.Entry::getValue) // return if value exists
.orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```